# Android emulator starting error

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

```
**In Starting of Emulator casue problem <br>** 
Starting emulator for AVD '4.2atom'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Open HAX device failed
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

when i am startin emulator of 4.2 atom image emulator on my window 7 -64 its give me error on starting